# How does video file with digital touch is formed in Messages (iMessage)?

Tags: ios, iphone, imessage

So can anyone help me in finding a way or the answer itself to above question. I am precisely looking for -whether the process involves merging two different frames (graffiti_frame & camera_frame I just have named them for simplicity)taken at same instant or resultant output frame has been made by changing camera recorded frame in accordance with swiped area on the screen during recording. Any insight related to it will be helpful. Thanks in advance.

Edit: The following is the link from apple official site about the feature with Title:**Add a sketch to a photo or video** [link](https://support.apple.com/en-in/HT206896)

Comment: This would be much easier to answer if you linked to a specific WWDC video describing the effect you mention or the appropriate developer SDK / sample code you found that’s closest to the animation you seek. Also - please don’t cross post here and the same question on other sites.

Comment: Thanks @bmike for your suggestion. And on cross post thing, I wasn't aware of that and will take care of that in future.